# How do I track how many users have used my app (React-Native Expo) with Firebase Analytics

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

How do I track the number of people who have used my app using Firebase Analytics? I have tried looking in the documentation for Firebase Analytics: [firebase.google.com/docs/analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics?hl=en&authuser=0) but couldn't find anything related to that statistic.

I think it is possible because in the Firebase Dashboard, there is a "User activity over time" graph even though I can't find any documentation.

My app is made with JavaScript, React Native and Expo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **[User activity over time](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317517?authuser=0#engagement&zippy=%2Cin-this-article)** graph shows the metric of active user that has engaged with your app in the device foreground, and has logged a *[user_engagement](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069#user_engagement)* event. This event is automatically sent by Google Analytics when a user navigates off the page, which happens when a user closes their tab or window or when they navigate to another page or screen. The event includes the session engagement status and user engagement duration. Though, note that the event isn't sent when an event was already sent less than 1 second before the event would have occurred. You could check out this [blog post](https://firebase.blog/posts/2018/12/new-changes-sessions-user-engagement) for more information about Google Analytics sessions and User Engagement.